# I am getting a result "[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000029FC870>]"? What's wrong with my code here

Tags: python, arrays, normalization

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self,coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates=coordinates
            self.dimension=len(coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be non empty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be iterable')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)

    def magnitude(self):
        mag = [(sum(x**2 for x in self.coordinates))**0.5]
        return Vector(mag)

    def normalize(self):
        mag= self.magnitude()
        normal= [((1/mag)*x for x in self.coordinates)]
        return Vector(normal)

vector_m=Vector([5.581,-2.136])
print vector_m.normalize()

vector_m=Vector([-0.221,7.437])
print vector_m.magnitude()
```

Comment: I see some thing wrong with your init, check if you intend to write  __init__

Comment: should it be `return mag` instead of `return Vector(mag)` ? The same with normal...

Answer (score 0):

This

```
normal= [((1/mag)*x for x in self.coordinates)]
```

creates a 1-element list containing a generator. The expression

```
((1/mag)*x for x in self.coordinates)
```

is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).  What you want instead is:

```
normal= [(1/mag)*x for x in self.coordinates]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However now I am getting the error "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'Vector'" . I understand that "mag" is a one value array, which I am trying to divide by 1. so I tried "inverse_mag=[1/x for x in mag]" after the mag statement, but then it gives me the error  "'Vector' object is not iterable". Any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: @AmitSinghParihar That's because `mag` is not a list. `mag` is a `Vector` object. You probably want `[1/x for x in mag.coordinates]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment univerio. That didn't solve the problem but it did give me an idea. Mag was still an array when I tried using it in multiplication.  so I extracted the only element in array mag, stored it in a different variable y, and then used that for multiplication with the array.                                                               mag= self.magnitude()
            mag=[1/x for x in mag.coordinates]
            y= mag[0]
            print y
            normal= [y*x for x in self.coordinates]
            return Vector(normal)